# Cannot get my animation to render properly

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I've created an animation that looks great in the 3d viewport, but I just cannot get it to render out. Sometimes it renders the same frame 250 times, sometimes it renders a few seconds and then the rest of the render is stuck on the same frame. (I've got all the quality settings low at the moment so I can quickly render out low-res videos and image sequences.) Sometimes it renders nothing at all. (I've tried unchecking the Compositing and Sequencer boxes in the Pipeline section of Post Processing in the Output Properties panel. Hasn't solved the problem.)

In my animation, there are a whole bunch of books that are funneled to a single point by two mesh planes (Rigid Bodies). I have hidden the planes from the render and the viewport (I need these books to crash down on a person filmed on a green screen).  Sometimes, though, the render shows the hidden planes, and not the books!

Any suggestions? I'm sure that I am missing some or a few important steps in the process. All help much appreciated!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is just a quick shot without further investigation... have you baked your rigid body animation? I sometimes got weird results when the physics are calculated "on the fly" while rendering the animation.

Comment: Yes, that's it!  Knew it was something obvious.  This noob is very appreciative. Thank you.